# Designing the web service to call another web service

Tags: c#, wcf

Task-1: My web service (wService1) will receive data block in XML format(Requester). The request data will contain as a minimum the username, password (secure service) and some data, say xyzdata. Now this xyzdata needs to be stored in a database(DB1).

Task-2: My above web service (wService1) needs to call the existing web service (wService2) passing all of the xyzdata  as required, performing any formatting.

Task-3: Now wService1 should be able to recieve response (in XML format) from wService2 and store the returned data against the relevant data in the database (DB1).

Task-4: wService1 should return the response to requester in XML format with relevant data.

As such I need to write my own web service (wService1) from scratch and call existing service, I am not able to figure out how should I design it. Also, I have no idea how to call one service from another web service.

Comment: Calling a web service from any C# code should be the same, whether that code is running as a web service itself or not.  However you're integrating `wService1` to what's calling it, you'd integrate `wService2` to the code driving `wService1` the same way.

Comment: Point of clarification... Are `wService1` and `wService2` _actually_ separate web services?  Or are they two web service methods in the same application context?

Comment: @David Means I just need to add the wService2 in my Service Reference and continue write the code using wService2's proxy class ? Both are separate web services.

Comment: Correct.  If they're separate web services, then each one is encapsulated.  You'd call a web service from one application just like you would from another application.  From the perspective of the code, there's no difference.

Comment: @David In the whole process, I have to work with XML data. So, if I use LINQ to XML to read the xml string, is that fine? As I only have experience to read from a xml file not with any webservice.